# S3 object got updated but last modified time not changed, how is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

There was a s3 object with the name report.csv. I downloaded the record around 4:00PM(I didn't see the last modified time in S3 console) and total record count was 250. later again I downloaded at 5:00PM it contains only 200 records but the last modified time shown in S3 console was 2:00PM.

Note: All the upload and download happened on the same day. Many people has access to that bucket. S3 Versioning was not enabled for that bucket and also i checked there is no other versions available for that particular object.

Also, I think it is not a browser cache problem, as I checked with a friend who was also faced the same issue for that object almost at the same time.

Is anyone faced similar issues or is it possible to update a S3 object with a fixed last modified time?

Comment: A user can't change `Last-Modified` value. This is a system defined object [metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata).

Comment: exactly, thats why I'm confused with this. is it possible if the object was restored then the last modified will also set to older one or the time it was restored?